# Aurelia Typescript project only working on Chrome

Tags: typescript, aurelia

Does anyone know why Aurelia-Typescript projects listed [in this git repository](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript) only functions on Chrome browser?

Are there ES6 features that are only currently supported on Chrome and not on IE or FireFox?

*EDIT* - below are the error messages from Firefox 34.0.5

mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly;
instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create core.js:130

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. index.html

"DEBUG [bootstrapper] loading the HTMLImports polyfill" core.js:2518

The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.

Error: Script error for: webcomponentsjs/HTMLImports.min
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:166

Comment: It should be working properly in all evergreen browsers at the moment.  Are you getting errors in the console on FireFox?

Comment: For me, running a Visual Studio project in Chrome runs fine.  If I switch to IE or Firefox, the Index page loads and displays but then it's stuck at that point waiting for app to load.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?  It must be outputting some reason that it is stuck...

Comment: Just added error messages from Firefox.  There is no error message on IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In aurelia-bundle.js at line 15346 (bootstrapper part) it checks whether HTML import is supported:

```
      if (!("import" in document.createElement("link"))) {
        logger.debug("loading the HTMLImports polyfill");
        toLoad.push(System.normalize("webcomponentsjs/HTMLImports.min", loaderName).then(function (name) {
          return System["import"](name);
        }));
      }
```

The only browser that supports it out-of-the-box is still Chrome. For the other browsers HTMLImports polyfill loading fails because:

1. HTMLImports.min.js is missing from **webcomponentsjs** directory
2. The path should be "aurelia/webcomponentsjs/HTMLImports.min". It might be better to move webcomponentsjs to the root path (I don't know how this can be handled through bundling)
3. Follow @Chi Row's answer below for HTML Template Element polyfill (IE 11 seems supporting them, so it worked without).

Comment: HTMLImports.min.js was there but the directory was under scripts directory.  When I moved the directory to the root, Firefox worked.

Comment: Scripts directory only exists in solutions: 'aurelia-vs-ts.sln' and 'aurelia-vs-ts-tests.sln' for the others you may download or copy from other solution.

Answer (score 3):

@T Sol's answer above solved the problem for Firefox.

For IE, I downloaded HTMLTemplateElements.js from [this git repository](https://github.com/aurelia/html-template-element) and placed the file in the root directory.  Then renamed the file to aurelia-html-template-elements.js.

That solved the problem for IE.