# Running Aurelia without a server in Firefox

Tags: firefox, aurelia, jspm

I know a lot of 'recent' JS tech **require** a server to work, but is there a way to run a simple **Aurelia** hello world without a server installation, just opening index.html and see my hello world app shown in the browser. It works for angular 1.x and many other JavaScript libraries.

Is the `System.import` mechanism going to force me to use a server ? Or is there a workaround to read local files, I tried the [usual hacks](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/overview.md#file-access-from-files) but it did not help as I still get `Error: [Exception... "File error: Unrecognized path"  nsresult: "0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH)"` but the path shown in the error (not pasted here) matches my local path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Aurelia starter pack recommends using Firefox to accomplish this goal if you are using the ES2016 starter kit. Firefox is the only browser that supports the use case you are asking about.

For any other browser, you will need to run a server. I recommend using the extremely simple to use `http-server` that runs on NodeJS.

From within your project directory type the following two commands:

```
npm install -g http-server
http-server
```

Then open your browser and navigate to http://localhost:8080 (8080 is `http-server`'s default port. This port can be changed using the `-p` command line argument.

Comment: I know how to run a server but I was not able to run it serverless in Firefox (even after changing the security property in about:config).

Comment: It may have to do with https://github.com/aurelia/loader-default/issues/29, I am using Firefox 44 and may this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796657/aurelia-typescript-project-only-working-on-chrome

Comment: I'd highly recommend using an environment that is at least somewhat close to what you are going to run in production. If you're deploying your app to the web, use a web server in development. +1 for http-server or `gulp watch` if you're using one of the Aurelia skeletons.

Comment: Got it working in FF now, I am not sure what cause the problem in the first place, probably some of my changes. Perhaps you could provide a simple zip download of Aurelia where it just works out of the box (without the whole npm, jspm, gulp setup) ? This would allow anyone to quickly test Aurelia with pure html/css/js and find out if they like it ?